# How to know the width of an UITableViewCell when using auto layout?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, autolayout

I have an `UITableViewCell` where I put in its `contentView` labels and other things using the auto layout. I added constraints, one of them being that the `contentView` has the same bounds than the `UITableViewCell`.

(On the `storyboard`, for convenience, I selected `iphone 4-inch` as the size of the `simulated metrics`.)

After adding the constraints, I call `layoutIfNeeded` as I need to get the size of my cells. The constraints are indeed laid out as I can see that my `contentView` is now the same size of the `UITableViewCell`. The problem is that the size of the `UITableViewCell` hasn't been adapted to the size of the screen yet (I guess it's done automatically later as my cells are fine). So I'm still on the size of an iphone 4 inches while I am on an iphone 4.7 inches.

Is there a way to trigger the final size of my cells like there is a way to force lay out using `layoutIfNeed`?

Comment: When do you call the `layoutIfNeed` method?

Comment: right after adding the constraint in `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`

Comment: I think the cell's superview is nil at the time. So the cell's width doesn't  update to tableView's width.

Comment: actually it's the size of the one I have in the storyboard

Comment: Yes, it's default size until it be added to tableView. So why are you getting the width of an UITableViewCell?

Comment: I have to add extra buttons (I want to make like the default swipe to delete but on the other side and other buttons) and didn't to make it with auto layout as I would apply the height of each row and a fixed width

Comment: Try to use constraints to the buttons in storyboard or in `cellForRow`. I think that is a better way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you load the cell from storyboard or nib, it has the specified size in the nib not the final one. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` add your views and constraint to the `contentView`, then adjust the width doing `cell.width = tableView.width`. Finally, call `layoutIfNeeded` as you were doing it before.

That will cause a complete layout with the correct width of the cell.

Edit: This works because even though you are loading the nib with autolayout enabled (`translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = NO`), the first view of every nib file has always autolayout disabled (`translatesAutoresizingMasksIntoConstraints = YES`).

This means that when rendering the view (so doing `layoutIfNeeded`), autolayout will consider the actual frame and masks property to determine the correct size.

Comment: Thanks it worked. Just needed to update the size of my view in `layoutSubviews`` method

Comment: that was very annoying issue. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to call layoutIfNeeded after adding constraints.

You can subclass your cell and override *- (void)layoutSubviews* method to get frame changes or you can add an observer to the cell if you don't want to subclass it.

```
[cell addObserver:yourObserver forKeyPath:@"self.frame" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

and then, in the observer's class

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if(object==cell && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"self.frame"]) {
        //your code...
    }
}
```

If it doesn't work, try to replace cell by cell.contentView.

Edit: If you want to create a subview by using constraints that matches the height of the cell and has a width of 100 and with is left aligned to the cell.

```
UIView *createdSubview = [[UIView alloc] init];
createdSubview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
[cell.contentView addSubview:createdSubview];

//Left align
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-0-[createdSubview]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(createdSubview)]];

// Fit the parent view height
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-0-[createdSubview]-0-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(createdSubview)]];

// Width constraint
[cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[createdSubview(==100)]" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(createdSubview)]];
```

Comment: But after calling `layoutIfNeeded` I add some subviews to my cell, and if I do it in `layoutSubviews` I get an infinite loop

Comment: You did not say you were adding subviews. Of course you can't add subviews in layoutSubviews since it will re-trigger the method, as the subviews change.

Comment: But I don't understand why you need to wait until your cell has its final size to add subviews. Why don't you create them in the storyboard, or just after the view is loaded? If you set up your constraints correctly, you can always modify them afterwards.

Comment: I didn't want to add constraints for those subviews as I would make them the same height than the cell and a fix width. And I create them programmatically, when creating the cell

Comment: The best thing is still to use constraints. I updated my answer so that you can see how to add subviews with constraints.

Comment: Thanks but in my case, constraints are a bit of a hassle for what I want to do (it's more complicated that I described)