# UIView's autolayout size reported from wrong size class the first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, size-classes

I have a UITableViewController with some custom cells and an UIView within each cell. I have implemented the controller's cellForRowAtIndexPath to configure the UIView in each cell. For this purpose I need to know the width of the UIView on screen. Since I am using autolayout and size classes to automatically change the size of the UIView based on device orientation, I have implemented an additional method of getting the width runtime.

The problem is that when the table view is presented the first time, my code reports width for UIVIew from a compact width size class even when I am using the device in the landscape orientation. The system renders all the views as should, but my code to get the width is not working. Scrolling new cells visible or an orientation change will remedy the situation immediately.

My code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { 

            // ...

            CustomCell* cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];

            if (cell == nil) {
                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib firstObject];
            } else {

                // Clear custom content

                NSArray *viewsToRemove = [cell.histogramView subviews];
                for (UIView *v in viewsToRemove) {
                    [v removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }

            [cell setNeedsLayout];
            [cell layoutIfNeeded];

            int width = ((CustomView*)cell.customView).getWidth;
            NSLog(@"width = %d", width);

            // ...

}
```

And then:

```
@implementation CustomView

- (int)getWidth {
    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    int width = self.frame.size.width;
    return width;
}

@end
```

Edited to add:

The problem seems to be that at when cellForRowAtIndexPath is called the first time tableview appears, autolayout has not occurred for the cell. Forcing it with [cell setNeedsLayout] and [cell layoutIfNeeded] right after creating the cell does not do the trick either.

It seems my problem root cause is a potential duplicate of [How to know the width of an UITableViewCell when using auto layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31264536/how-to-know-the-width-of-an-uitableviewcell-when-using-auto-layout) So the problem has to do with fact that when my CustomCell is loaded from a nib, it will have the default frame. Special tricks should be done to force autolayout. However, the accepted answer does not work for cells that are initially out of visible area. Any takers on this?

Comment: When is this being called? Make sure it's in viewDidAppear or later. If it's called in viewWillAppear or viewDidLoad, it won't be sized yet.

Comment: It's called from cellForRowAtIndexPath as it is needed for configuring the cell contents. The call is visible on the snippet.

Comment: Why don't you use size class dependent autolayout for your custom content in the cell?

Comment: I am. But my UIView content requires runtime calculations which is why I need to know the width after autolayout. My code for getting that is unreliable and that it the reason for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the correct solution to this:

1. Create a custom cell like in the original question.
2. Set `cell.contentMode = UIViewContentModeRedraw` in `tableview: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`
3. Implement `layoutSubviews` for the custom cell like so:

   `- (void)layoutSubviews {
       [super layoutSubviews];
       NSLog(@"cell width == %f", self.bounds.size.width);
   }`

This way you will have access to the size of the cell as it will appear on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying to use constraints and ratios instead of actual width of the frame, since, as stated by Marcus Adams, the frame will have the value you are actually looking for only after viewDidAppear.

For example if your cells contain a UILabel that is 1/3 the width of the cell, and a UIImageView that fills the space left, you can set constraints between them and the parent view.

Can your logic be changed like this?

Another suggestion would be to call reloadData on your table view after viewDidAppear, but that is definitely not a nice option UX-wise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The UIView within my cell has constant constrains to its width set up using storyboards. Portrait and landscape modes (size classes) will have separate widths. How could I determine which one will used for displaying the UIView during cellForRowAtIndexPath in order to configure UIView's contents properly, which rely on dimensions runtime?

Comment: Can you provide more details on what exactly you want to be different for views in portrait and landscape? I think this can be solved by using specific constraints for that size class, but I'm not sure I understand why you really need that information when configuring your cells.

Comment: So suppose I have a UIView within a UITableViewCell. For one size class (portrait) I want the UIView's width to be 100. For another size class (landscape) I want the UIView to be of width 150. I have set this up and it works. Now, I have to fill the UIView with whatever I want that cannot be configured with autolayout. To implement that I need a way to probe the UIView's width run time. Only the problem is, when the cell and UIView are about to appear and loaded from a nib, the autolayout has not occurred and the default width from the nib is reported during cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Once the cell and the UIView reappear on the screen (scrolling them off and back) the correct width is known using my method, so my code almost works.